# SO does not allow me to post although I am selecting a TAG

Tags: support, tags

Trying to post a question about R in stack overflow I am getting a message saying:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

```
you need at least one valid tag; see a list of popular tags
```

Although I select R as tag I still cannot post....

Any idea how I can go around?

Comment: Can you take a screen shot where you selected the tag and post it as an edit to this question? It should *just work* once you've selected a valid tag, and `R` is a valid tag.

Comment: Like everyone's said, [tag:r] is a valid tag and this should work just fine. But really, this should be a definite edge case. I imagine that in 99% of cases there are at least *two* appropriate tags for a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't work around it - there's no way to submit an untagged question.

Make sure when you type `r` into the tag box you then click on the tag in question to get a blue tag like this:

[image]

That's your clue that you've chosen a valid tag. As I understand it, it should work if you just type in `r`, but it's worth checking.

Comment: That's an impressive FHRC you have there!  Did you have to use [all nine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142852/ninefingers) of your fingers? ;)

Comment: @Lix I used the GIMP - so yes. There are so many floating panels I'd never hold them all down without all these fingers I have. No idea how people with just eight fingers cope!